# What is the equivalent to UIViewController methodology for OSX?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am new to OSX development.

Before storyboards on iOS, when you created a single view application, you would end with this structure:

```
AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate.h
ViewController.h
ViewController.m
ViewController.xib
```

The app would start on the `delegate` and call the `xib` and its classes, so the entry point to the app would be `viewDidLoad` inside `ViewController.m`

I have created an app for OSX. All I have is

```
AppDelegate.h
AppDelegate.m
MainMenu.xib
```

I would now to recreate something like the `ViewController.h` and `ViewController.m` and transfer control to something like a `viewDidLoad`, but I see this MainMenu.xib of cocoa has a window inside.

What do I do? Create a custom class for this window? I did not see any equivalent to `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear`, etc. What is the equivalent for NSWindow or if this is now how it is done, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppDelegate should have a `applicationDidFinishLaunching` which you can use as the entry point. the AppDelegate has a window associated with it by default. You can use AppDelegate to create the various features you would like to use. An alternative is to create a subclass of NSWindowController  and have an associated xib for that which you can load when you want. Hope this helps.